# Fill td height with anchor

Tags: html, css

```
<td style="padding: 8px;">
  <a href="#" style="display: block; height: 100%;">test</a>
</td>
```

I'm trying to make a clickable table cell, using `display: block` on an anchor fills the width of a `td`, but height is still not filled - the anchor has the height of `test` text, not the `td` height with padding.

How can I do this?

Comment: if you want to fill the whole `td` with your `a` tag you have to add the `padding` to your `a` tag instead of adding it to the `td` tag

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding from td and add padding to

```
<a href="#" style="display: block; height: 100%;padding: 8px;">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table><tr>
<td style="border:thin black solid; background:gray;">
  <a href="#test" style="display: block; height: 100%;padding: 8px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">test</a>
</td></tr></table>
```

Remove padding from `td` and give it to `a` tag.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td style="height: 100%;">
  <a href="#" style="display: block;padding: 8px;"> test</a>
</td>
```

set height to `td` and set padding to `a`